# How can i get particular li's previous li class name?

Tags: jquery, menu, html-lists

i have menu structure like below,

```
<ul>  
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1406 current_page_item menu-item-7482 white">one</li>

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1406 current_page_item menu-item-7482 orange">two</li>

   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1406 current_page_item menu-item-7482 white">three</li>

  <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1406 current_page_item menu-item-7482 orange">four</li>

  <li class="signup_login orange"><a title="Sign up" href="/login?status=d&amp;login=setsignup" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'AmerTypeMdBTMedium' ! important;"> sign up </a></li>

  <li class="logout white"><a title="Login" href="/login?status=d&amp;login=setlogin" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'AmerTypeMdBTMedium' ! important;"> login</a></li> 
</ul>
```

in the above i need to check li which has class name "signup_login" previous li class. based on that i need to set class for last two li's.

for that i used below jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    if(($('.signup_login').prev('.white'))){
      $('.signup_login').addClass('orange');
      $('.logout').addClass('white');
    } else {
      $('.signup_login').addClass('white');
      $('.logout').addClass('orange');
    }
)};
```

but it won't work. what is the problem with the above jquery code?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($('.signup_login').prev('li').hasClass('white')) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

prev() doesn't return it has the class or not. it just return previous element.
so you should try

```
$('.signup_login').prev().hasClass('white')
```

kinda code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".signup_login")
    .siblings()
    .each(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass("white") ){
            // has white class
        } else {
            // doesn't have white class
        }
    });
```

This will check all the `li`'s siblings and, if they have the proper class, do whatever you want to them.